# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined at Object.eval - Service object cannot bind to ngModel in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I have an object declared in my **service**:

```
public caseDetails = {
partyId: '',
address: {
      state: '',
      city: '',
      zip: '',
      street: ''
    }
}
```

I need to bind the objects to a input box. Here is what I could do

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="this.serviceObj.caseDetails.partyId">
```

Here is the what **I can't** do

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="this.serviceObj.caseDetails.address.state">
```

I could bind if the object declared in my component. But I can't bind to a service object. Here is the error details:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Comment: Whether or not the object is in the service or in the component wouldn't change anything. You've just not initialized caseDetails.address, so it's undefined, so you can't access any of its properties. Also, there should be no `this` in your Angular expressions.

Comment: You cannot do it like that. In your component declare a variable say caseDetailsFrmService and then initialize it with the object from service and then access caseDetailsFrmService  in your html.

Comment: @JBNizet The code works with a component object but not with service object.

Comment: @Florian - that is not issue , it working at my end both service and class you can check my answer and have try

Comment: If you want to render properties, the angular pattern is to create your properties inside the component. Component block purpose is to manage the view(template). Service should be use to implement logic.

Comment: i provided working asnwer have look and try at your end , working for me , and hope you like to remove -1

Comment: @PranayRana : I didn't vote, if you have a -1, it's not me sorry ! By the way, I strongly believe that any data displayed have to be managed by the component class...

Comment: @Florian - -1 comment is for the OP, and I do agree with you one should only bind value from component..but i answered question because i am thinking OP is playing around angular

Comment: Could you add a warning or something to explain him why he is doing wrong (mismatch between service/pattern). I will then upvote you !

Comment: @Florian - hmm updated my answer with code itself , hope OP get my point :)

Comment: is that worked for you ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** it not recommended way to bind data from service object directly, it's better you get data from service and store in local variable to component and do work on that. An example:

**component.ts**:

```
export class abcComponent implements OnInit {
 datafromService:any;
 constructor(
    public service: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.datafromService = service.caseDetails; 
  }
}
```

**html of component then**:

```
{{datafromService|json}}
{{datafromService.address.state|json}}

   <form>
       <input name='test' type="text" 
        [(ngModel)]="datafromService.address.state">
   </form>
```

*Service-code* there is no change.

---

Below is working tried and tested at my end.

**service.ts**:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class DataService {

  public caseDetails = {
    partyId: '',
    address: {
      state: 'mystate',
      city: '',
      zip: '',
      street: ''
    }
  }
}
```

**component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'abc',
  templateUrl: 'abc.component.html'
})
export class abcComponent {
 constructor(
    public service: DataService
  ) { }
}
```

**component.html**:

```
{{service.caseDetails|json}}
{{service.caseDetails.address.state|json}}

   <form>
       <input name='test' type="text" 
        [(ngModel)]="deskService.caseDetails.address.state">
   </form>
```

---

There is issue that you used `this`, it should be

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="serviceObj.caseDetails.address.state">
```

for this to work `serviceObj` need to be `public` so it will work

Comment: @AnasBinNazeer - hi can  you do {{serviceObj.caseDetails|json}} on your component

Comment: @AnasBinNazeer - updated code which is working at my end without any issue , how you like to revert you -1 point and try out solution...